# Why is Python able to parse Amazon but not Google/Reddit?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've searched for awhile to no result. Python seems to be able to handle some-- but not all--webpages:

```
import requests, webbrowser, bs4
res = requests.get('http://www.reddit.com')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
print soup.prettify()
```

Surprisingly, this is able to print the Amazon.com homepage, but not Reddit. The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "testweb.py", line 7, in <module>
print soup.prettify()File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xd7' in position 37769: character maps to <undefined>
```

My question: How can I write a program that can encode for any webpage? Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: Further testing shows google.com also does not work. It's a similar error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "testweb.py", line 7, in <module>
print soup.prettify()File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xa9' in position 9651: character maps to <undefined>
```

EDIT 2: Tried decoding res.text to utf-8 but got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "testweb.py", line 5, in <module>
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text.decode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 9358: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Edit 3: Tried encoding res.text to utf-8 but got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "testweb.py", line 8, in <module>
print soup.prettify()File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xa9' in position 9622: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: You could try decoding `res.text` to `utf-8`: `res.text.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: Just tried it, still got an error :(. Edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the output encoding to `utf-8`, so it'll output utf-8 encoded text, and try to encode the request text, instead of decoding it.

Example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests, webbrowser, bs4
res = requests.get('http://www.reddit.com')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text.encode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')
print (soup.prettify())
```

Try to encode directly in `prettify`:

`print (soup.prettify('latin-1'))` or `print (soup.prettify('utf-8'))`

Comment: Still doesn't work. Updating post with this method. Thank you.

Comment: Check the update to verify if it can help you. @KendrickTV